# Create a new work order / ticket in BMC TrackIT using external content types in Sharepoint

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath

BMC TrackIT uses an SQL database, so we'd be using an external content type in SharePoint to create the new work order / ticket. What tables require updating to create a new work order and ensure email notifications get triggered?

On the SharePoint side, we have a custom list with an Infopath form that receives the request. Then a workflow duplicates the submitted request in the external list, which then triggers the configured SQL operations. That's the theory.

Has anyone done this successfully? Thoughts?

Cheers,
Bill

Comment: I haven't used TrackIt in years (didn't even know BMC acquired it).  But I'd suggest not editing base tables - most manufacturers won't support the product if they realize you're doing that.  Not sure what version you have, but it looks like there are published APIs which you would be safer using if possible https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-27973

Comment: Thanks - agreed. Directly editing the DB makes me nervous. We're trying to allow users to submit tickets via a web form in SharePoint. Problem is, we're using Infopath forms and TrackIT receives the email from the email address set in SP Central admin - all email out of SharePoint comes from this address. We'd like it to come from the user, so the requester is auto logged in TrackIT. Infopath does not allow this. Any other ideas that would not involve editing database tables?